Stop CMake from exporting dependencies
I am compiling a shared object using CMake (3.24) for Linux using gcc. For better code management, I have split our code into multiple static libraries that I combine together along with dependencies into a final shared object. I am statically linking to all my dependencies.
Here is the final CMakeLists.txt that combines the sub-projects into shared object.
project(myProject)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED library.cpp)
find_package(OpenSSL GLOBAL REQUIRED) # ${OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY} and related vars are correct

set(CMAKE_THREAD_PREFER_PTHREAD TRUE)
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG TRUE)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

... find_package for other static dependencies, correct ...

set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -fPIC)
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC 
  ... List of my sub-folder includes ...
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE 
  ... List of sub-projects here ...
  CURL::libcurl
  OpenSSL::SSL 
  OpenSSL::Crypto 
  ZLIB::ZLIB 
  Threads::Threads 
  stdc++fs
)

The library gets built correctly and runs as expected, however, when I look at the dynamic symbols exported in the shared object I can see all my dependencies are exported too. For example, I can see most/all CRYPTO_ and OPENSSL_ symbols in the nm -D output.
$ nm -D libmyProject.so
...
0000000000f1a50f T CRYPTO_128_unwrap
0000000000f1a784 T CRYPTO_128_unwrap_pad
0000000000f1a12e T CRYPTO_128_wrap
...
0000000000f2b704 T OPENSSL_asc2uni
0000000000f0b61e T OPENSSL_atexit
0000000000fa85c0 T OPENSSL_atomic_add
0000000000f1b64c T OPENSSL_buf2hexst
...

This is causing clashes when others use my library, who are trying to use their own version of the dependencies. My understanding was that if I link statically, it should not export these symbols.
Things I tried to solve this:

Setting visibility preset to hidden - that hides my symbols by not the dependencies!

set(CMAKE_C_VISIBILITY_PRESET       hidden)
set(CMAKE_CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET     hidden)
set(CMAKE_VISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN YES)


Adding a --retain-symbols-file option with a list of only my symbols, didn't work - this still exported everything.
Adding a --version-script option with a list of only my symbols, this worked - but is causing my test apps to act very strangely. Without any code changes, test app compiles + links but all my tests fail. I suspect it is because the versioning is causing a strange behaviour. Trying to get the version script to work seems like overkill to me

target_link_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE 
  -Wl,--retain-symbols-file=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/myProject.exp
  -Wl,--version-script=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/myProject.version-script
  -Wl,--export-dynamic -rdynamic
)

It feels like exporting just my symbols from a static library to a shared object should be easier than this. What am I doing wrong? Are my dependencies compiled incorrectly or with wrong options?
SOLUTION
Finally managed to solve this, specifically with the fixes mentioned here Library load error when compiled with -fvisibility=hidden in Linux. As OP also found, Drepper's paper on how to write shared libraries was very informative.
What I did for anyone else stumbles on this:

Added -Wl,-z,defs to make sure all dependencies were resolved right now and not left as undefined. Since everything is linked statically, this is important.
Added -Wl,--exclude-libs,libssl.a:libcrypto.a

My final linker options were:
target_link_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE 
  -Wl,-z,defs
  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libssl.a:libcrypto.a
)

Running nm on output binary does not have any OpenSSL or Crypto symbols in either dynamic or text sections.
$ nm -gCD libmyProject.so | grep " CRYPTO_" | wc -l
0

My next steps are to restrict visibility via attributes, but that is not pertinent to this SO question, so omitting that here.

Are you sure you're linking openssl statically?  What's the actual link line when cmake builds your final target?

And if your users are linking against both their own openssl and your library, I'm pretty sure all bets are off even if you're statically linking internally.  There's probably a dupe here, and it's not limited to just cmake.

Running make VERBOSE=1 shows what I'd expect: cd /scratch/myProject && /usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/myProject.dir/link.txt --verbose=1 /usr/bin/c++ -fPIC  -pthread -Wno-unknown-pragmas -g -shared -Wl,-soname,libmyProject.so -o libmyProject.so  CMakeFiles/myProject.dir/library.cpp.o  /scratch/myProject/deps/libcurl/lib/libcurl.a /scratch/myProject/deps/openssl/lib/libssl.a /scratch/myProject/deps/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a /scratch/myProject/deps/zlib/lib/libz.a -lstdc++fs -pthread -ldl

No one links to the output shared lib. Currently I am running strip on the output to restrict further linking, but plan to add -s once this is fixed.

@StephenNewell does the -g option have an effect on the dynamic symbols or just the data section?

-fvisibility=hidden is a compiler flag. You need to compile your dependencies this way. If you have pre-made binaries, it's too late. --retain-symbols-file works for me just fine. If it doesn't work for you, please post a [mcve].

Note also that you may need to link your shared library with -Bsymbolic so that symbols from system libraries linked by your users do not preempt your private ones.

libssl.a you are linking together .a files, not .so. Are you compiling openssl? I do not follow. Is /scratch/myProject/deps/libcurl some directory you created? How it got created? Can you not use it?
